# How to find log likelihood of Gamma, Log normal and Weibull?

Tags: r, weibull, gamma-distribution

I want to find the log likelihood of data given Gamma, Weibull and Log normal distributions in R. How do I proceed given that I have already estimated the parameters of the respective distributions?

Comment: Consider posting example data and functional code that estimates the parameters.

Comment: These links [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats4/html/mle.html), [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Maximum_Likelihood) and [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/paper/CompStat/maxLik.pdf?revision=1114&root=maxlik&pathrev=1114)  would be good starting point.

Comment: This sound like a request to do your homework, but without the actual question.

Comment: i have done my parameters estimation as follows:fitdistr(x,'Gamma')
     shape       rate   
  451.76954   202.13089 
 ( 31.96263) ( 14.30864)
fitdistr(x,'Weibull')
      shape          scale    
  20.618605163    2.285169506 
 ( 0.696335843) ( 0.005879705)
fitdistr(x,'lognormal')
     meanlog        sdlog   
  0.803152625   0.047006742 
 (0.002353281) (0.001664021)
now i want to find the respective log likelihood @ Mark Miller

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example for Gamma.  Weibull and log-Normal follow exactly the same procedure.

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rgamma(20,shape=3,rate=2.5)

library(MASS)
(ff <- fitdistr(x,"gamma"))
##     shape       rate  
##   4.452775   4.175653 
##  (1.358630) (1.348722)
```

`fitdistr` has a log-likelihood accessor method:

```
logLik(ff)
## 'log Lik.' -13.14535 (df=2)
```

Or you can do it by hand:

```
sum(dgamma(x,shape=coef(ff)["shape"],rate=coef(ff)["rate"],log=TRUE))
## [1] -13.14535
```

or a little bit of sugar/R-magic:

```
with(as.list(coef(ff)),
      sum(dgamma(x,shape=shape,rate=rate,log=TRUE)))
```

For the other distributions

- `densfun="weibull"` -> `dweibull()`
- `densfun="lognormal"` -> `dlnorm()`

In both cases the parameterizations/names of the parameters match between `fitdistr` and the corresponding density functions.